# How does Java code executing within JRuby getResourceAsStream from its own jar?

Tags: java, jruby

I am using JRuby, and I am having trouble loading a resources from a jar file.

I load jar file. The java code inside the jar file attempts to load one of its own resources MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/a_resource_inside_the_jar"); That works in pure java, but in the JRuby rails app, it cannot find the resource. Is this a bug?

1. My rails app requires jar
2. My rails app imports class MyClass
3. My rails creates a new instance of MyClass and calls the do_something method in MyClass.
4. The do_something method internally calls MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/a_resource_inside_the_jar.txt") as part of its business logic.
5. Inevitably, I always get a null input stream, even though the same Java code works in Java without Ruby.

What is the work around for this, or the right way to handle resources in a jar file?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it should work the same, and it does work the same. There was a typo in my resource name and therefor it did not actually exist, thus null was returned.